# GNU assembler- How to use .ifdef with logical AND,OR

Tags: if-statement, gcc, assembly, arm, gnu-assembler

In C I am able to use

```
#if defined(MULTI_CORE) || defined(CORE_INDEX)
```

How to achieve the same result in arm assembly file (using .ifdef or .if or any other supported expression)? I am using GCC compiler toolchain.

Comment: If you rename your assembly file with `.S` extension, you can use _C_ preprocessor directives like `#if`, `#ifdef` etc as well as _C_ macro processing etc in your assembly file

Comment: I looked for a duplicate and didn't find one, so I guess I'll turn those comments into an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use C preprocessor syntax in `.S` files exactly as you would in `.c` / `.h`.  Build your code with `gcc -c foo.S` (not `as` directly), which causes `gcc` (the compiler front-end) to run your file through CPP before feeding it to `as`.

Thus CPP stuff happens entirely before and separately from any `.if` GAS macro stuff.

`.ifdef` and other GAS macro functionality isn't designed to replace CPP. You're *supposed* to use CPP (or `m4` or whatever) as a preprocessor for your asm source.

---

Note that using `as` directly on a `.S` will often build without error messages on x86, because `#` is the comment character in GAS syntax for that target. e.g. put `#if 0` / `#endif` around some instructions: they will be in `foo.o` after `as -o foo.o foo.S`.  All the `#if` lines are treated as comments.

On ARM you should get noisy failure, because the comment character is `@` (`#` is used in immediates).  If you really wanted to guard against accidentally building without CPP on any platform, you could `#define THIS_FILE_NEEDS_CPP` then on the next line write `THIS_FILE_NEEDS_CPP THIS_FILE_NEEDS_CPP`.  (Twice so it's not a valid label declaration).  With CPP macro processing, this becomes a blank line instead of an invalid insn.  `as` removes `//` and `/* */` comments on its own, so you can't just use that.  But most people don't do anything special; their build scripts work and they don't randomly build `.S` files without CPP.

See also:

- [Use of ifdef in gas assembly language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46272497/use-of-ifdef-in-gas-assembly-language).  (`.ifdef` tests for symbols, not `.macro` macros)
- [gnu arm assembler command line macro fails with "Invalid identifier for .ifdef"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12768306/gnu-arm-assembler-command-line-macro-fails-with-invalid-identifier-for-ifdef) (CPP turned `.ifdef MACRO_FROM_CMDLINE` into `.ifdef 1`).